# Special Select for Dynamic Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code us for selecting all array in current selection:

```
Sub SpecialSelectDynamicArrays()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dynamicArray As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.HasSpill Then ' Check if the cell is part of a spilled range
            If dynamicArray Is Nothing Then
                Set dynamicArray = cell ' Set the first found spilled range
            Else
                ' Add to the existing dynamic array range if it doesn't already contain this spill
                If Intersect(dynamicArray, cell) Is Nothing Then
                    Set dynamicArray = Union(dynamicArray, cell)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    If Not dynamicArray Is Nothing Then
        dynamicArray.Select ' Select the combined dynamic array ranges
    Else
        MsgBox "No dynamic arrays found in the selection.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to improve this code for it to work in a big model. So instead of looping through every cell, it should exclude Blank cell from the selection. Something like anti-union.

I have been looking for way to do anti-union but it is a bit difficult to find.

Comment: Do you use Excel 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` - it will only return cells with a formula. In case of array formulas only the "source"-cell of the formula. By that you are reducing the amount of cells to be checked.

If you then use `SpillingToRange` you will retrieve the "result"-range of a dynamic formula.

```vb
Sub SpecialSelectDynamicArrays()

Dim rgToCheck As Range, c As Range
Set rgToCheck = Selection

Dim dynamicArray  As Range

For Each c In rgToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If c.HasSpill Then
        If dynamicArray Is Nothing Then
            Set dynamicArray = c.SpillingToRange
        Else
            Set dynamicArray = Union(dynamicArray, c.SpillingToRange)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not dynamicArray Is Nothing Then
    dynamicArray.Select ' Select the combined dynamic array ranges
Else
    MsgBox "No dynamic arrays found in the selection.", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```